# Error when match is not found when using Find method

Tags: excel, vba, find

I know this probably has extensive coverage, and I've tried a few of those, but still can't get it to work:

```
        Dim d As Range
        For Each d In orng
            Dim val As Range
            Set val = adws.Range("O2:O" & lrw).Find(d.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole).Offset(0, 26)
            
            If val Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox d.Value & " not found."
                End
            Else
                d.Offset(0, 12) = val.Value
            End If
        Next
```

Code works fine as long as the function finds a value, but gets error on the first one that it does not. Setting the val variable and running the Find function on the same line, I got from other forums. But this doesn't seem to work at all. Find still gets confused when it can't find a value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.Offset(0, 26)` is problematic. Don't chain any calls to the `Find` call, instead only `Offset` *after* you've ensured the `Find` succeeded.

Also consider using another variable name than `Val` as that shadows the [`Val`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) function.

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = adws.Range("O2:O" & lrw).Find(d.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
           
If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox d.Value & " not found."
    End
Else
    d.Offset(0, 12).Value = rng.Offset(0, 26).Value ' Offset here since Find succeeded
End If
```